# Binary Search Trees Max Height

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def getHeight(self, root):
    if not root:
        return -1
    else:
        return (max(self.getHeight(root.right), self.getHeight(root.left)) + 1)
```

I was doing a python problem related to binary search trees and the instructor wrote a line of code like this,

```
return (max(self.getHeight(root.right), self.getHeight(root.left)) + 1)
```

I am not sure how this works. Could someone explain to me why it is like this?

Comment: Do u understand how recursion works?or you have problem with the return line only?

Comment: New with recursion

Comment: "The height of a tree with given root is one more than the max height of the subtrees rooted at its children."

Answer (score 0):

This is recursion method to find the height of BST.

```
if not root:
      return -1
```

The above is base condition, when you reach  to right or left node of node leaf node then function returns -1 .

The return statement can written  simply as:

```
    left_height=height(root.left)
    right_height=height(root.right)
    return 1+max(right_height,left_height)
```

Where you get the height of left subtree and right subtree recursively and then add 1 to  the maximum  of them because we consider that tree with height 0 has -1 height ,so add 1.
You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_pnqMz5nrRs&vl=en) simple tutorial.